# Jmeter does not return same json response as Postman

Tags: jmeter, postman

I have one GET Request to Get `access_token`.

Postman Response is :

```
{
    "token_type": "Bearer",
    "expires_in": 3599,
    "ext_expires_in": 3599,
    "access_token": "eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJSUzI1NiIsIng1dCI6ImppYk5ia0ZTU2JteFBZck45Q0ZxUms0SzRndyIsImtpZCI6ImppYk5ia0ZTU2JteFBZck45Q0ZxUms0SzRndyJ9.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.Mj3FnWRbAmpTbGpqfsda2_9SxSY-VTlCFALk-_4-2JLTZXY-dszAoupeArmJDztliETBqzGlXP7xtOls8SV_0fafZXhTxpkKuntV1d0N0l5XqmEt1Uz6vE_LMJTyzfH_OtrDBRXHEJshgKfdvXJ0eywGAFoBUSEpwlKKbg2BB-0kUJ5itFLPq5TipwL35FxUklkZ6qjB4ySG3Xuhr_dEyLu7oUhBdArX-bBVRrcsOhatVfExNq3YtVMVEO96E7hH2H7jupH4nXu1BcRJ5WkymQTV-Sg1ccF0GgxBLrk1rYjacNGlKf8SFjs3USJl2P7HHtVtS3fDSc8t5pQ7Jt5lXQ"
}
```

Jmeter Response :

```
It is kind of html and something like :

<!-- Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved. -->
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html dir="ltr" class="" lang="en">
<head>
    <title>Sign in to your account</title>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=2.0, user-scalable=yes">
    <meta http-equiv="Pragma" content="no-cache">
    <meta http-equiv="Expires" content="-1">
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://aadcdn.msauth.net" crossorigin>
<meta http-equiv="x-dns-prefetch-control" content="on">
<link rel="dns-prefetch" href="//aadcdn.msauth.net">
<link rel="dns-prefetch" href="//aadcdn.msftauth.net">

    <meta name="PageID" content="ConvergedError" />
    <meta name="SiteID" content="" />
    <meta name="ReqLC" content="1033" />
    <meta name="LocLC" content="en-US" />

        <meta name="referrer" content="origin" />

    <noscript>
        <meta http-equiv="Refresh" content="0; URL=" />
    </noscript>

    
    
<meta name="robots" content="none" />

<script type="text/javascript">//<![CDATA[
$Config={"strHeaderText":"Sign in","unsafe_strTopMessage":"Sorry, but we’re having trouble signing you in.","strMainMessage":"We received a bad request.","strAdditionalMessage":"","strServiceExceptionMessage":"AADSTS900561: The endpoint only accepts POST, OPTIONS requests. Received a GET request.","}
```

Looks like Jmeter response is asking for login but in postman I never login to anywhere to get token. I just imported collection and it works.

Jmeter Header :

[image]

Comment: Did you add content-type header?

Comment: Yes @user7294900. I just added same in question.

Answer (score 0):

> "unsafe_strTopMessage":"Sorry, but we’re having trouble signing you
> in.","strMainMessage":"We received a bad
> request.","strAdditionalMessage":"","strServiceExceptionMessage":"AADSTS900561:
> **The endpoint only accepts POST, OPTIONS** requests. **Received a GET
> request**.","}

It looks like you have GET method your JMeter HTTP Request Sampler. But he endpoint only accepts POST , OPTIONS. Can you compare the method in working Postman request

Also compare the headers in the Postman request and the JMeter HTTP Request Sampler. Ensure name and value pairs are comparable. Check if you have included spaces in the names/values in header manager. You need to click on the fields and ensure there are no leading or trailing spaces.

Answer (score 0):

I was doing the same for Azure. I think you need to change your request to be POST, and, contrary to any logic, put in the body the authentication parameters in a non-JSON format:

[HTTP Request](https://i.stack.imgur.com/m644Q.png)

Later on, add an HTTP Header Manager with the same information:

[HTTP Header Manager](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TseVH.png)

References:

1. https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/fill-forms-and-submit-with-jmeter-made-easy
2. https://powerusers.microsoft.com/t5/Building-Flows/Get-access-token-error-AADSTS900144/td-p/732173
3. https://github.com/postmanlabs/postman-app-support/issues/3685
4. https://www.swtestacademy.com/jmeter-tutorial-api-performance-testing/

P.S. StackOverflow doesn't allow me to upload images yet so you would need to click on the links.

Answer (score 0):

> The endpoint only accepts POST, OPTIONS requests. Received a GET
> request.

Looks like you need to submit your request as a POST, not a GET.